# Google leader board not working in signed build

Tags: android, leaderboard

i just implemented Google Leader-Board inside my application , i have created project in game services , i provided app description under GAME DETAILS , added logo and feature icon. then **i linked the application by providing my application package name and then Authorize the application by providing SHA 1** which i get from eclipse under **window > preferences >Android> build > SHA fingerprints** , Then i added 5 Achievements and then added new leaderboard.

After filling all above detail it starts displaying App ready to publish.

After this i generate keystore and build a signed apk to upload it on console under "All Application" , before publishing the application i published the Game service and then published the app in console. Now when i run application through code leader-board get displayed on screen but when i run signed apk it shows popup saying **"Application is incorrectly configured.Check that the package name and signing certificate match the client iD created in DeveloperConsole"**

Please let me know the reason , where does SHA 1 get different in all this process.

As per suggestions i generated SHA1 using below command and created new leaderBoard in game services and linked that with my existing Published application.I even cross checked the SHA1 fingerprint of my signed build using :-

> unzip YourGame.apk keytool -printcert -file META-INF/CERT.RSA

Command use to generate SHA1 fingerprit from keystore :-

> keytool -exportcert -alias your-key-name -keystore
>   /path/to/your/keystore/file -list -v

So the finger prints from above and below command was similar.

Now , My version 2 which is published on playstore start displaying leader board but it's shown message saying "**Hmm something  went wrong in playstore**"

**Have anyone got this issue earlier ?**

**Do i need to make separate keystore with new package name of application and create fresh leader board in game service and then launch both on playstore freshly ?**

```
                         **OR**
```

**Is this occurring because my first version contains different leader board which i unpublished now and have created new leader board under game service and bin that with my version 2 of application ?**

Thanks

Comment: have you tried this https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting ?

Comment: Generate SHA1 by using release keystore/jks instead of debug.kestore and add in this google apis console.

Comment: Hey @sandeepmaaram can you please provide me example here ? as i found the SHA1 through command line and SHA1 from eclipse are same. Please provide me example to generate it.

Comment: While generating signed apk we used to create new kesytore or use existing keystore, right? use that keystore in below command. keytool -exportcert -keystore path-to-production-keystore -list -v

Comment: Okay , this is what you are saying keytool -exportcert -alias the wollen group -keystore /home/ravi/Desktop/abc/IAPGame/IABgitBucket/keystore/keystore -list -v ?

Comment: Yes. But in command should with .keystore extension. Ex. If keystore name as sample, then command is like keytool -exportcert -keystore keystorepath/sample.keystore -list -v

Comment: Thus this alias name matters ? i mean i am having the wollen group , so it's displaying Illegal option:  wollen

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it was caused by creating the OAuth 2.0 client ID for my release build using Google API console instead of Google Play Console.

I fixed it by deleting that client ID and creating a second linked app as described [here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting).

The troubleshooting page states:

> You must create the new client ID in the Google Play Console, not in the Google API Console.
>   If you are debugging your game using your debug certificate but have configured games services using your release certificate, you should add a second linked app using the same package name and your debug certificate's SHA1 fingerprint. This will allow you to sign in to the application whether it's signed with the debug or release certificates.